# Showing years 1995-2000 in "Select features using expression" in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have an attribute table that shows states, years, and other specific things of that state in that year.  How do I create an expression (so I can export a shapefile with these selected features) that:

- Selects a state
- Selects only the years 1995-2000 of that state

`"st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' AND "yr" = '1996'` etc.

does not work...

---

Solution:

"st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' OR "yr" = '1996' OR "yr" = '1997'

Comment: Put quotation marks missing. "st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' AND "yr" = '1996' etc.

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake in my post, Francisco! I should have just copied and pasted what I actually had typed inside QGIS.  Unfortunately even when the proper quotation marks are added this doesn't display any results (0).                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' AND "yr" = '1996' AND "yr" = '1997'

Comment: put "st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' OR "yr" = '1996' OR "yr" = '1997'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select *different* years you need to use `OR` rather than `AND` between your years.

`"st" = 'CA' AND "yr" = '1995' OR "yr" = '1996'`

Using `AND` tells it to select each individual record that has a year 1995 AND 1996 AND 1997 etc., where each record only has a single year against it.

Comment: I don't know QGIS, but there may be better ways to do the selection, such as `"st" = 'CA' AND "yr" IN ('1995', '1996', '1997')` which would select any records where ST is CA and the Year is at one of the values in the list

Comment: I'm going to try that right now because it would be easier in the future for similar projects, but your first suggestion definitely works for me too.